# In Windows Vista and 7, I can't access the %DEFAULTUSERPROFILE% system variable - it shows as not found

Tags: c#, windows-7, windows-vista, environment-variables

If I try to access this system variable from the Run... dialog, Windows tells me the directory doesn't exist. Some system variables, like %SYSTEMROOT% and %USERPROFILE%, do work. Consequently, if I try to use a supposedly nonexistent variable like %DEFAULTUSERPROFILE% or %PROFILESFOLDER% in C#, I get nothing in return. Is there something special I need to do to get access to these variables?

Comment: Given that `%DEFAULTUSERPROFILE%` is only used when creating new users, why do you want it?

Comment: For that matter, are you sure this is a system variable?  I can't see it on Windows XP SP3's cmd, and attempting to Run it results in an error.

Comment: R. Bemrose: I'm using the list of environment variables that MS has here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560744%28WS.10%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to retreive that value directly from the registry - in case you can't expand it:

```
public static string GetDefaultUserProfilePath() {
    string path = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DEFAULTUSERPROFILE") ?? string.Empty;
    if (path.Length == 0) {
        using (Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList")) {
            path = (string)key.GetValue("Default", string.Empty);
        }
    }
    return path;
}
```

Comment: Don't directly poke around in the registry trying to get stuff that has a standard API. You'll just create more headaches for Raymond Chen.

Comment: That worked - thanks!

I'd still like to know why all the environment variables laid out in http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560744%28WS.10%29.aspx#BKMK_1 don't work, but I'll use the registry entry for now.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%`?

Comment: for some inexplicable reason, that points to C:\ProgramData. I need to point to C:\Users\Default\AppData. I could get the profiles directory from the registry, but that seems like a bad idea for some reason.

Comment: ALLUSERSPROFILE is shared data for all users, the default profile is the basis for new user profiles

Answer (score 2):

> I need to point to
>   C:\Users\Default\AppData.

Are you sure?  Be aware that this folder is used to populate the inital AppData directory for each new user added to the system.

If you want the actual shared application data directory in .NET, it's this:

```
String commonAppData = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolders.CommonApplicationData)
```

Comment: Well, what I'm doing is making an app to add games to the Games Explorer. It seems like if the game doesn't have its own GDF.dll (which is currently how I plan on making the app behave), the game has to be referenced by a shortcut either in \Users\$username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\GameExplorer\ or \Users\Default\...

Answer (score 0):

You mention C# - you can't use environment variables inside C# path strings, you need to replace them using [System.Environment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.aspx).

```
System.Environment.GetEnvironmentalVariable("USERPROFILE");
```

I haven't seen `%DefaultUserProfile%` before - should it point to the first username that was installed?

Comment: %DefaultUserProfile%, according to Microsoft, points to HKLM\Micrsoft
Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList [Default]

Answer (score 0):

Call [SHGetFolderLocation](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32/shgetfolderlocation.html) with CSIDL_PROFILE and -1 as the token parameter